# Rust fails to compile after adding geo crate

Tags: rust

I am using `alpine-3.16` and `rust-1.56` with the following packages to compile my program.

```
expat libbz2 libcrypto1.1 libffi libpq libssl1.1 libtirpc libuuid musl \
    ncurses-libs readline xz-libs zlib libc6-compat rust cargo bash
```

I was able to compile my program before adding the following two dependencies:

```
geo = "0.22.1"
geo-types = "0.7.6"
```

Following are the full contents of `cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "math-helpers"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies.cpython]
version = "0.7.0"

[features]
default = ["python3"]
python3 = ["cpython/python3-sys", "cpython/extension-module"]

[dependencies]
libm = {version = "0.2.0"}
geo = "0.22.1"
geo-types = "0.7.6"
```

The errors that I am getting are as following:

```
/math-helpers # cargo build
   Compiling geo v0.22.1
error: there is no argument named `pt`
   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/geo-0.22.1/src/algorithm/sweep/line_or_point.rs:248:59
    |
248 |                     "line intersection before first line: {pt:?}\n\tLine({lp1:?} - {lp2:?}) X Line({lp3:?} - {lp4:?})",
    |                                                           ^^^^^^

error: there is no argument named `pt`
   --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/geo-0.22.1/src/algorithm/sweep/line_or_point.rs:256:60
    |
256 |                     "line intersection before second line: {pt:?}\n\tLine({lp1:?} - {lp2:?}) X Line({lp3:?} - {lp4:?})",
    |                                                            ^^^^^^

error: there is no argument named `r`
  --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/geo-0.22.1/src/algorithm/sweep/segment.rs:51:79
   |
51 |                 "intersection point was not ordered within the line: {p:?} <= {r:?} <=> {q:?}",
   |                                                                               ^^^^^

error: there is no argument named `q`
  --> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/geo-0.22.1/src/algorithm/sweep/segment.rs:51:89
   |
51 |                 "intersection point was not ordered within the line: {p:?} <= {r:?} <=> {q:?}",
   |                                                                                         ^^^^^
```

It works fine on Ubuntu, though. It's highly likely that I am missing a platform dependency that needs to be installed on Alpine.

Comment: That style of format string got stabilized with [Rust 1.58](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2022/01/13/Rust-1.58.0.html#captured-identifiers-in-format-strings). You could downgrade to an older version of [geo](https://lib.rs/crates/geo/versions), but probably upgrading your Rust is a good idea. (Also, making a PR to `geo` to add `rust-version = "1.58"` to the `Cargo.toml` may be nice.)

Comment: @Caesar Make than an answer.

Comment: Thanks! Updating the Rust to the latest version fixed the issue.